# Why does this MySQL error near group by statement?

Tags: mysql

I want to group my table with `mem_num` and it appears error saying that :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by m.mem_num' at line 6.

Here's my code.

```
select m.mem_num, count(d.vid_num) as total
from membership m
inner join rental r on m.mem_num = r.mem_num
inner join detailrental d on r.rent_num = d.rent_num
having count(d.vid_num) > 1
group by m.mem_num;
```

For a clearer view click here to view the image
:
[output query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kmcs.png)

Comment: The `HAVING` clause goes after the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) to learn how to create a valid sql statement in mysql. You will notice that there is an order between the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAVING belongs after the GROUP BY

```
select m.mem_num, count(d.vid_num) as total
from membership m
inner join rental r on m.mem_num = r.mem_num
inner join detailrental d on r.rent_num = d.rent_num
group by m.mem_num
having count(d.vid_num) > 1;
```